# OSMDroid - Heat Map

Tags: android, heatmap, osmdroid

Good morning, I want to create a Heat Map layer in Android OSM MapView. I found the `heatmap.js` library, that is the way I want, but I don't know how to use it on Android with OSMDroid. If have anybody idea how to use this great library with OSM Droid it will be all I want.

My idea is to make random shapes on the map from a few points (one point == one heat, NOT heat by points in same place), but the heat canvas must stay solid at all zoom levels.

I want to have stored some points in database (see below) on web and if the user clicks a button, the MapView will render the heat canvas (with selected diameter), and if user zoom in/out the canvas will zoom too, but will not split to many points adjacent.

And next thing is, that the heat map will have about 4 colors, where red will have the biggest value (percents of quality) and the further the point, the smaller will be the value (same ratio, so it will render in app).

I was also searching on Google and I saw the Resources Game app pictures, which shows something similar, as I need.

The Database looks like this:

```
| lat | lng | value |
---------------------
rows...
```

(lat = latitute, lng = longitude, value = percents of quality)

I will be very excited about any advice and I apologize for my English.

The following two pictures show how I want it to look like, and how after zoom (sorry, pictures should be same size).

Normal Zoom
[image: Normal Zoom]

After Zoom
[image: After Zoom in]

Comment: Not exactly what you're looking for, but it's a start https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/OpenStreetMapViewer/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/samplefragments/data/HeatMap.java

Comment: @spy Thank you for answer. It looks good, but how can I use it? I have BonusPack.